# How many threads can a C++ application create

Tags: c++

I'd like to know, how many threads can a C++ application create at most.
Does OS, hardware caps and other factors influence on these bounds?

Comment: Yes, in general, time and space limit the amount of threads.

Comment: At the moment, this question is too broad for anyone to give a useful answer. Could you explain why you need to know this information? Why are you considering creating a huge number of threads?

Comment: In Hell++, a random number is generated during compilation, and that is the maximum number of threads allowed for that program.

Comment: It depends on your operating system and compiler. If you want to know, just create a lot of threads and record the first std::system_error.

Comment: I presume that it's legal to have a limit of zero threads and comply with the standard (other than the default thread of course)?

Comment: my linux system shows it can handle only 60604 threads

Comment: @jcoder yes, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: Well, shit

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: what is your problem with that?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: I need moar threads dammit. And jQuery. I need jQuery, too

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: haha

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: Good grief, if that is true, how do you bubble-sort an integer array with more than 121208 elements?

Comment: @Damon: but threads are not needed there right?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: Of course not, I was being ironic as this is a _"What is the maximum possible amount of [something I only ever reasonably need 5 or 6 of anyway]"_ type of question.

Comment: @Damon: Ya you are right. The OP is trying to test the limits that the language and the system can offer him

Comment: Which of course is not needed to be tested

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C++ as language does not specify a maximum (or even a minimum beyond the one). The particular implementation can, but I never saw it done directly. The OS also can, but normally just states a  lank like limited by system resources.   Each thread uses up some nonpaged memory, selector tables, other bound things, so you may run out of that. If you don't the system will become pretty unresponsive if the threads actually do work.

Looking from other side, real parallelism is limited by actual cores in the system, and you shall not have too many threads. Applications that could logically spawn hundreds or thousands usually start using thread pools for good practical reasons.

Answer (score 23):

> `[C++11: 1.10/1]:` *[..]* Under a hosted implementation, a C++ program can have more than one thread running concurrently. *[..]* Under a freestanding implementation, it is implementation-defined whether a program can have more than one thread of execution.
>
> `[C++11: 30.3/1]:` 30.3 describes components that can be used to create and manage threads. *[ Note:* **These threads are intended to map one-to-one with operating system threads.** *—end note ]*

So, basically, it's totally up to the implementation & OS; C++ doesn't care!

It doesn't even list a recommendation in *Annex B "Implementation quantities"!* (which seems like an omission, actually).

Answer (score 11):

Basically, there are **no limits** at your C++ **application level**. The number of maximum thread is more on the **OS level** (based on your architecture and memory available).

**On Linux**, there are no limit on the maximum number of thread per process. The number of thread is limited system wide. You can check the number of maximum allowed threads by doing:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

**On Windows** you can use the [testlimit](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/TestLimit.zip) tool to check the maximum number of thread:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx

**On Mac OS**, please read [this table](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3854) to find the number of thread based on your hardware configuration

However, please keep in mind that you are on a **multitasking system**. **The number of threads executed at the same time is limited by the total number of processor cores available**. To do more things, the system tries to switch between all theses thread. Each "switch" has a performce (a few milliseconds). If your system is "switching" too much, it won't speed too much time to "work" and your overall system will be slow.

Comment: @DeadMG Based on your feedback, I have added an answer for Windows too.

Comment: @poiuytrez: There are more than two OSs in the observable universe. And then there are the other universes to consider.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit An almost infinite number of OS like the number of planets. I do not want to be banned from SO to have them all listed in an answer.

Comment: @poiuytrez: This is why abstract specifications exist -- we may answer within the scope of the C++ standard, as requested!

Comment: However, part of the point is that the scope of the C++ standard does not limit it and thus the info on the actual limits that one is *likely* to run into is greatly appreciated, making this one of the best answers so far.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the limit of number of threads is the amount of memory available, but there have been systems around that have lower limits.

Unless you go mad with creating threads, it's very unlikely it will be a problem to have a limit. Creating more threads is rarely beneficial, once you reach a certain number - that number may be around the same as, or a few times higher than, the number of cores (which for real big, heavy hardware can be a few hundred these days, with 16-core processors and 8 sockets).

Threads that are CPU bound should not be more than the number of processors - nothing good comes from that.

Threads that are doing I/O or otherwise "sitting around waiting" can be higher in numbers - 2-5 per processor core seems reasonable. Given that modern machines have 8 sockets and 16 cores at the higher end of the spectrum, that's still only around 1000 threads.

Sure, it's possible to design, say, a webserver system where each connection is a thread, and the system has 10k or 20k connections active at any given time. But it's probably not the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to know, how many threads can a C++ application create at most.

Implementation/OS-dependent.

Keep in mind that there were no threads in C++ prior to C++11.

> Does OS, hardware caps and other factors influence on these bounds?

Yes.

OS might be able limit number of threads a process can create.
OS can limit total number of threads running simultaneously (to prevent fork bombs, etc, linux can definitely do that).
Available physical(and virtual) memory will limit number of threads you can create IF each thread allocates its own stack.
There can be a (possibly hardcoded) limit on how many thread "handles" OS can provide.
Underlying OS/platform might not have threads at all (real-mode compiler for DOS/FreeDOS or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the general impracticality of having many more threads than cores, yes, there are limits.  For example, a system may keep a unique "process ID" for each thread, and there may be only 65535 of them available.  Also, each thread will have its own stack, and those stacks will eventually consume too much memory (you can however adjust the size of each stack when you spawn threads).

Here's an informative article--ignore the fact that it mentions Windows, as the concepts are similar on other common systems: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/29/444912.aspx

Comment: Having more threads that can be extremely practical if you care about non-blocking asynchronous calls.

Comment: Having many more threads than cores is extremely practical if you care about synchronous calls that block.

Comment: `Apart from the general impracticality of having many more threads than cores` Huh?

Comment: _many_ being the operative word. An oustanding async IO needs an order of magnitude less resources than an entire waiting thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the C++ standard that limits number of threads. However, OS will certainly have a hard limit.

Having too many threads decreases the throughput of your application, so it's recommended that you use a thread pool.